# passing a variable from one ajax call to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this codepen [Localweather App](http://codepen.io/Casfan/pen/ZOWmdv?editors=1111) I have created two functions.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() {

  var city = "Newcastle";
  
  city = getLocation();
  //set city to location from function; 
  console.log ("city undefined?" +city);
  //this is undefind, why?
  
  getWeather(city).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
    var weatherId = data.weather[0].id;
    var tempF = Math.round(data.main.temp);
    var tempC = Math.round((tempF - 32) / 1.8);
    var wind = data.wind.speed;
    var name = data.name;
    console.log(weatherType);
    $('#weather').html(weatherType);
    $('#temp').html(tempC + "&#176;C");
    $('#wind').html(tempF + "&#176;F");
    $('#icon').html(weatherId);
    $('#location').html(name);
  
  })
});

function getLocation() {
  $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    console.log("data" + data);
    city = data.city;
    console.log("city" + city);
    return city;
  })
}

function getWeather(place) {
  return $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + place + '&units=imperial&APPID=90d625c068e3f3d7818b9e4237871e21');
}
 </script>
```

A getWeather function that takes in a place and returns a weather object for that location. I also have a getLocation function that I want to return my city based on ip ( yes I know its not accurate but its what I want to use).

If I hardcode the city it works. 
But trying to use the city Variable from the getLoction function isnt working.
I am guessing it is something to do with it been asynchronous but I though that by using a call back in the getLoction function it would return the 'city' which would 'then' be passed into the getWeather.
Or have I got my thinking all wrong?

Comment: What do you get in the console. log calls?

Comment: You need to work with (nested) callbacks.

Comment: You should chain your method calls, so on success of getLocation call getWeather with received data. Look here how ajax callbacks works: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with (nested) callbacks, because you need to wait for the async responses from your AJAX calls.

Your browser will not wait for async functions to finish and keep on running to the next statement, that's why city is undefined in your code - because in your code `getLocation` only returns a value when the `getJSON` finishes.

If your function would loook like this, you would get a return value, just not the one you want (so don't use this next code snippet, it's only there for the sake of explaining).

```
function getLocation() {
  $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
    return data.city; // this will be ignored, because the browser will jump to the next statement
  });
  return "XXX"; // <- this will be returned, because the browser will not wait for async functions to finish
}
```

In the example below we pass a function as parameter to `getLocation`. The parameters name is `callback` and we call this function with the `data` parameter when `$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io'` is done.

From this data parameter we can extract `city` and then call `getWeather`.

Notice how `getLocation` no longer returns any value, instead it passes the `data` parameter to the callback (or you could extract `city`in `getLocation` and then pass `city` to the callback instead).

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    getLocation(function(data) {
      var city = data.city;
      getWeather(city).then(function(data) {
        // ...
      });
    });
  });

  function getLocation(callback) {
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
      callback(data);
    });
  }

  function getWeather(place) {
    return $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + place + '&units=imperial&APPID=90d625c068e3f3d7818b9e4237871e21');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you explane the flow to me. It may not be technically correct but are we passing most of the program into the get location function.

Comment: The flow explains itself. You need the city/location first, before you can call getWeather. Like I said, your browser will not wait for AJAX calls to finish, that's why you have to chain the calls and work with callbacks. Yes, getLocation will be the starting point of your program, so make sure to "outsource" the code into functions (that take callback parameters), or else it will be hard to read and understand what the code does. Please mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

`return city;` in `getLocation()` only returns from the anonymous function `function(data)` that was passed into `$.getJSON`. Your `getLocation` doesn't actually have a `return` statement which makes `city = undefined`

One approach to handling this could be to make use of the `getJSON` Promise:

```
getLocation().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    getWeather(data.city).then(...
});
```

Then `getLocation` would look like:

```
function getLocation () {
    return $.getJSON(...
}
```

As you can see from the answers, there are many ways to go about this using `nested callbacks` or [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

[Here you can see my codepen in action](http://codepen.io/vincentwilkie/pen/dXpbyo)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to chain AJAX calls, you need to set the next AJAX call inside the callback of the previous one. This way, the next AJAX call will only be sent after the previous one has completed.

This answers is a slight variation that uses IP address to fetch latitude/longitude (instead of city) & then uses that for weather.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOpEBQ

```js
var ip = '8.8.8.8';

$.get('https://ipapi.co/'+ip+'/latlong/', function(data){
  
  data = data.split(',');
  console.log(data);
  
  $.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+data[0]+'&lon='+data[1]+'&units=imperial&APPID=90d625c068e3f3d7818b9e4237871e21', function(data1) {
    
    // Should print the weather
    console.log(data1);  
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

City would still be undefined because `getWeather` will not wait for `getLocation` to be performed and assign a value to city.  You could allways put

```
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(data) {
console.log("data" + data);
city = data.city;
console.log("city" + city);

$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&units=imperial&APPID=90d625c068e3f3d7818b9e4237871e21');
})
```

or you can use a `jQuery.Deferred()` object to only perform get weather when get city is done.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to wait for the ipinfo callback before call openwheater, otherwise city will be undefined, this is an async call mechanics

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  getLocation().then(function(city){
      getWeather(city.city).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
        var weatherId = data.weather[0].id;
        var tempF = Math.round(data.main.temp);
        var tempC = Math.round((tempF - 32) / 1.8);
        var wind = data.wind.speed;
        var name = data.name;
        console.log(weatherType);
        $('#weather').html(weatherType);
        $('#temp').html(tempC + "&#176;C");
        $('#wind').html(tempF + "&#176;F");
        $('#icon').html(weatherId);
        $('#location').html(name);

      }, function(err){
        console.log("ERROR!", err);
      })
  }, function(err){
     console.log("ERROR!", err);
  });
});

function getLocation() {
  return $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io');
}

function getWeather(place) {
  return $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + place + '&units=imperial&APPID=90d625c068e3f3d7818b9e4237871e21');
}
```